# three js camera movement to point

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I'm actually working on a website using three.js. You can see a demo here: https://c9.io/frescogusto/demi/workspace/demi_0.3.html
It's on canvas to be viewable on ios and android.

Question is: how do I move the camera from its position to the position of the object that has been clicked? Do I have to use *translate* method on every axis or there is a faster way?

thanks in advance

pp

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. how do i move the camera from its position to the position of the object that has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
        renderer.devicePixelRatio * (event.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / this.width * 2 - 1,
        - renderer.devicePixelRatio * (event.pageY - this.offsetTop) / this.height * 2 + 1,
        0.5
    );
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(
        camera.position,
        vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize()
    );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(YOUR_CLICKABLE_OBJECTS);
    if (intersects.length) {
        camera.position = intersects[0].point;
        // Alternatively, camera.position = intersects[0].object.position.clone();
    }
}, false);
```

This code:

- Registers a listener on the `mousedown` event
- Projects the clicked location in 2D screen space into a location in 3D scene space
- Casts an imaginary line (a *ray*) from the camera towards the click
- Checks whether any objects intersect with that line; the first object to intersect is the one that was clicked
- Snaps the camera to the clicked position

If you'd rather transition the camera slowly to the clicked location instead of snapping it there immediately, you may want to look into a tweening library like [TweenJS](https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS) to help you with the timing of the transition.

(P.S.: I think `renderer.devicePixelRatio` is only present for the WebGL renderer. You can just remove it for other renderers.)